# Apache Rewrite Redirect with dot in url

Tags: rewrite, httpd, mod-alias

In .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.info
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.info/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

In server .conf file:

```
Alias "/.well-known/acme-challenge" "/tmp/.well-known/acme-challenge"
```

Problem is that when I call:

> www.domain.info/.well-known/acme-challenge/someString

It is redirect to bad URL:

> www.domain.info.well-known/acme-challenge/someString

First slash is missing. Do you know why please? Without this rewrite is all ok.

Comment: I would implement this using a separate virtual host for `domain.info`, so that this `RewriteCond` would not need to be evaluated on every request to this host. I don't know if that would solve the rewrite issue though.

Comment: No, this is not right solution for us. Many users dont want this redirect. It is in user-created .htaccess.

Comment: Well, then they already have their own virtual host, and then the RewriteCond is not needed.

Comment: Hm, I need solution for it - no that is not needed it.